# DependencyAttribute class in F#

Tags: xamarin.forms, f#

I am working though Petzold's Creating Mobile Apps Using Xamarin Forms book, translating the C# code into F# where the F# code is not available on GitHub (he stopped posting FS after chapter 7).  In chapter 9, page 189, he makes use of the Dependency attribute like this:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(DisplayPlatformInfo.iOS.PlatformInfo))]
namespace DisplayPlatformInfo.iOS
{
  public interface IPlatformInfo
 {
 string GetModel();
 string GetVersion();
 }
  using System;
 using UIKit;
 using Xamarin.Forms;
  public class PlatformInfo : IPlatformInfo
 {
 UIDevice device = new UIDevice();
 //etc...
```

I want to do the equivalent in F#.  I created the type and the only place I can add that attribute is at a generic do() statement:

```
type PlatformInfo () =
    [<assembly: Dependency(typeof(Greetings.iOS.PlatformInfo))>]
    do()

    interface IPlatformInfo with
        member this.GetModel () = 
            let device = new UIDevice()
            device.Model.ToString()
        member this.GetVersion () = 
            let device = new UIDevice()
            String.Format("{0} {1}", device.SystemName, device.SystemVersion)
```

The problem is that I get a

> warning: attributes are ignored in this construct.

How should I be placing this attribute into the type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assembly level attributes in F# need to be a in module, at the top level.

I would translate the C# above as:

```
namespace rec DisplayPlatformInfo.iOS

// Make a module specifically for this attribute
module DisplayPlatformAssemblyInfo =
    [<assembly: Dependency(typeof(Greetings.iOS.PlatformInfo))>]
    do ()

type IPlatformInfo =
    abstract member GetModel : unit -> string
    abstract member GetVersion : unit -> string

// ... Implement your type, etc
```

Comment: The error on the attribute is now "this is not a valid constant expression or custom attribute value".

Comment: "The generic function "typeof" but be given explicit type arguments" is the runtime error

Comment: the problem is that the type that implements the Interface needs to be defend before the module so the typeof <> can find it

Comment: @Jamie dixon just put it at the end of the file (or use namespace rec)

Comment: I wrote up what I found here: https://jamessdixon.wordpress.com/2018/06/20/creating-mobile-apps-with-xamarin-forms-and-visual-studio-for-mac-using-f/

Answer (score 1):

Since it is an assembly attribute, it should be place at the top level of a module instead of in a type. The following should be working:

```
[<assembly: Dependency(typeof(Greetings.iOS.PlatformInfo))>]
do ()

type PlatformInfo () =
   // ...
```

Comment: I know, that's what I wrote! But you are right I should have make that more explicit in the code example. Yours is perfect! :-)

Comment: It's just that given is code I assumed implicit module: "If a code file does not begin with a top-level module declaration or a namespace declaration, the whole contents of the file, including any local modules, becomes part of an implicitly created top-level module".

Comment: Yes, but he needs this in a namespace for the attribute